# regex: not match a group rather than single characters

Tags: regex, sed

```
echo test.a.wav|sed 's/[^(.wav)]*//g'
.a.wav
```

What I want is to remove every character until it reaches the whole group `.wav`(that is, I want the result to be `.wav`), but it seems that sed would remove every character until it reaches any of the four characters. How to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups do not work inside <kbd>[]</kbd>, so the dot is part of the class as is the parens.

How about:

```
echo test.a.wav|sed 's/.*\(\.wav\)/\1/g'
```

Note, there may be other valid solutions, but you provide no context on what you are trying to do to determine what may be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're requesting wouldn't be supported by `sed` (*negative lookahead*) but Perl does the trick.

```
$ echo 'test.a.wav' | perl -pe 's/^(?:(?!\.wav).)*//g'
.wav
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex, you can use `awk` like this:

```
echo test.a.wav.more | awk -F".wav" '{print FS$2}'
.wav.more
```

It splits the data with your pattern, then print pattern and the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/^\.wav/!s/.//;ta;/./!d' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/\.wav/\n&/;s/^[^\n]*\n//;/./!d' file
```

N.B. This deletes the line if it is empty. If this is not wanted just remove `/./!d` from the above commands.